# Error for fencing calculation program

Tags: python

I am aiming to create a program in python which allows the user to input the cost of fencing per meter, the length and width of a paddock and the program should calculate and print the perimeter and then also the quoted price. I Have run into a few issues and my research on Stack Overflow has unfortunately been unsuccessful. My code is as follows (keep in mind I am just a beginner)

```
    from turtle import*
print ("Welcome to the fencing quote calculator")
print ("In this program, you will be able to input the size of the padock as well as the cost of the fence per meter")
again = ""
perMetre = input(str(("Please input the cost per metre in numbers without a dollar sign")
width = input("Please input the width of the paddock in metres")
length = input("Please input the length of the paddock in metres")

perimeter = (width+2)
print ("The perimeter of this paddock is",perimeter)
cost = int((perimeter)*(perMetre))
print("{:.2f}".format(cost))
```

The error is the TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly error code.
If you could please explain this in very simple terms I would really appreciate it.
Thanks :)

Comment: You're missing two right parentheses in the `width =` statement.

Comment: `perMetre` should be converted to integer or float. same goes for `width`. that is, if you're using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comments in replacement code below.

```
from turtle import*
print ("Welcome to the fencing quote calculator")
print ("In this program, you will be able to input the size of the padock as well as the cost of the fence per meter")
again = ""
perMetre = input(str(("Please input the cost per metre in numbers without a dollar sign")
width = input("Please input the width of the paddock in metres")
length = input("Please input the length of the paddock in metres")

# need to convert "numbers" currently input as strings to floating point numbers
perMetre = float(perMetre)
width = float(width)
length = float(length)

# also fix perimeter equation?
#perimeter = (width+2)
perimeter = (width + length) * 2.0
print ("The perimeter of this paddock is",perimeter)
cost = perimeter * perMetre
print("{:.2f}".format(cost))
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. All working now. Keep up the great work :)